# How do I install nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 so that I can have upstream config files

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I use ubuntu 16.04. I have removed nginx config

$ sudo rm -rvf /etc/nginx/

purged nginx and installed it again

```
# apt-get remove --purge nginx
# apt install nginx
```

aptitude shows nginx installed

## aptitude search nginx

```
p   lua-nginx-websocket                                - Lua websocket client driver for the nginx embedded Lua langu
i   nginx                                              - small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server                  
v   nginx:i386                                         -                                                             
i A nginx-common                                       - small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files   
i A nginx-core                                         - nginx web/proxy server (core version)                       
p   nginx-core:i386                                    - nginx web/proxy server (core version)
```

but command # ls /etc/n* shows no nginx config files installed?

what is going on?

---

following this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/361902/how-to-install-nginx-after-removed-it-manually

I have removed nginx and installed again. while installing i got following warnings.

```
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Comment: solved --- http://askubuntu.com/questions/361902/how-to-install-nginx-after-removed-it-manually says at the end 

So if you want to recreate the /etc/nginx files, you should do:

> apt-get install --reinstall nginx-common

Comment: If you have the solution, please post it as an answer, not as a comment. It would help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to recreate the /etc/nginx files, you should do:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall nginx-common